# GWT standard hello world application: No dynamic controls

Tags: gwt

I installed GWT into Eclipse and created a project "hello".

I start the application using "Run as" > "Web Application"

When opening localhost:8888 I get an alert box
"GWT project 'hello' may need to be (re)compiled."

When I click okay, I get

"Web Application Starter Project
Please enter your name: 
"

but no input box or buttons apear.

Comment: Have you checked the project console for any stack traces or errors? More often than not, this is because GWT is having trouble compiling the code for whatever reason. Command line compiling will give a clear picture of the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project -> Google -> GWT Compile solved the problem.